# How does any command work in OS?

Tags: linux, macos, operating-system

I use osX and I am curious to know when I type any command, how does it work? How does Operating system know where to find the binaries?

There is a `/bin` folder in the **`root`** directory which contains binaries for `cat, mv, mkdir` etc.

some are in `/sbin`

Some binaries are in `/usr/bin` like `python`. some binaries are in `/usr/local/bin` like `node`.

My question is when I run the command, How does OS know from where to pick the binaries? why not all the binaries are at one place or at least the symlink are placed at one location?

Do other Operating systems manage this differently like Linux or windows or the working fundamental is same for other OS as well?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Some binaries and files are in different places because they are critical and needed earlier in the system boot sequence before larger filesystems with other binaries are mounted - e.g. `fsck`. Some files are specific to one machine and therefore in `/etc` and others are shared amongst machines with the same basic OS to save disk space on all machines on a network, and also to make updates easier if they only need patching in one place (eg. `/usr/share/man`). Some binaries are supplied by the OS vendor and some are only locally installed sometimes (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`).

Answer (score 1):

There is a PATH environment variable, just like linux, and even MSWin; PATH is a list of directories delimited by colon character (:).  Your Terminal window is actually running bash, so it should be familiar if you use linux.  bash searches each directory in turn until it finds executable; if it fails to find it, you should get the "bash: commandUtyped: command not found" message.  You should be able to enter "type commandUwantToType" to figure out where bash is finding the executable; if you use "-a" after "type," bash will tell you *every* place it finds the command (hashed, alias, function, file, etc.).  Use "help type" to get more information on "type" command.

Answer (score 1):

> why not all the binaries are at one place or at least the symlink are
>   placed at one location?

This has a lot to do with the hierarchy of the file system. For example, `/bin` contains binaries which are used by the system when running in single user or multi-user mode. `/usr/bin/` contains binaries for common utilities and applications. [This](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) is the hierarchy of the [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org) (parts of the Mac OS are based on this OS) file system. And [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html) is some excellent documentation.